# Compare difference in files located in different directories in PuTTY

Tags: diff, sh

I want to compare files in separate directories in a PuTTY session.

I tried to run this command:

```
diff -b /path/file1 /path/file2
```

PuTTY returned this error:

> sh: diff: cannot execute - No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong here? Does PuTTY not support the diff command?

Comment: Just make sure that the files exist ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: PuTTY is not the issue; it's just a terminal emulator.